# Why is the IP and host specified in the /etc/hosts not pinged as expected?

Tags: macos, networking, router, dns, mac-address

I have an entry in my /etc/hosts file which points to each host on my LAN.  I've completed specified all my hosts and corresponding host mac addresses in my Time Warner supplied router.  I've created hosts files which are the exact representation of what is specified in that router IP <-> mac address mapping, and put the corresponding host entries in each of my hosts' /etc/hosts file.  Most of the hosts on each host can be pinged by the names given in the corresponding /etc/hosts file.  But there are a few which do not work.  Here is an example:

```
whmcclos@c3p0 ~
$ grep ubu /etc/hosts
192.168.0.24    linuxvm1,ubu    #00:1C:42:3A:7F:63

whmcclos@c3p0 ~
$ ping ubu
PING ubu.socal.rr.com (67.215.65.132): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 67.215.65.132: icmp_seq=0 ttl=54 time=19.654 ms
^C
--- ubu.socal.rr.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 19.654/19.654/19.654/0.000 ms
```

I would have expected this ping to attempt to reach 192.168.0.24, but it does not.  I've also tried using the other symbolic name, linuxvm1, and it also tries some hose at linuxvm1.socal.rr.com, and nothing happens.

So why is my OSX 10.6.8 server not using its /etc/hosts file to resolve the symbolic address names, ubu & linuxvm1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entries in `/etc/hosts` are space-delimited; not comma-delimited.  Remove the comma from this line:

```
192.168.0.24    linuxvm1,ubu    #00:1C:42:3A:7F:63
```

so that it appears thus:

```
192.168.0.24    linuxvm1 ubu    #00:1C:42:3A:7F:63
```

Comment: DopeGhoti- Did the trick. Thanks for noticing that.  Should have read the `man -S 5 hosts`.